# What do these numbers mean on the right side of the different Stack Exchange Communities?

Tags: support, user-interface, top-bar, communities-list

I'm not sure what these numbers are referring to, i.e. the 79, 11, 11, 1, 1.

[image]

Comment: Right-click → Inspect element. You’ll find the class name `rep-score` there, referring to reputation score.

Answer (score 7):

These numbers are **your current reputation score** in each of these Stack Exchange communities.

Currently you have 79 on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13384365/anthony-schrayer), 11 of [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/254141/), 11 on [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/57720/), 1 on [Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/49716/), and 1 on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/778584/). (Also 1 on [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/265371/), but that dropdown menu will only show your top 5 sites.)

The numbers displayed in that dropdown menu will change as your actual reputation score on the various sites changes.